# Логика построения MVP приложения с несколькими View-Presenter

Tags: java, swing, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

К сожалению, все примеры из сети, которые я нашел, содержат примитивную логику построения MVP. Все компоненты инициализируются и связываются в main-методе. А как быть если пар View-Presenter N-ое число? Например, это могут быть модальные окна, или вкладки. Кому, с точки зрения архитектуры, будет правильно делегировать логику создания и инциализации нового View и связи его с Presenter ? Фабрике ?

DI использовать не получается, поскольку возникает круговая зависимость. View нужна ссылка на Presenter, а Presenter нужна ссылка на View.

Буду признателен за пример, или ссылку на рабочее swing приложение, использующее MVP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел ответ свой вопрос. Логика инциализации может быть передана View или Presenter, в зависимости от выбранного паттерна: Supervising Controller или Passive View. [Тут подробное описание](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431252). Всем спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки не добавляют знаний в Рунет.